# My jquery form is not working in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I have problem with making this form to work in Firefox but it works perfectly in Goole Chrome. I can see in network, after I press button, that is calling test.php and then I get error: object, object... I have no clue which part of Ajax function dose not work in Firefox and how to fix it. Hope someone can help me :)

```
$(document).on('submit','form#myform',function(){
  $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url: '/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/test.php',
           data: $('form').serialize(),
           success: function(data) {
              $( "#addEmilInfo").append( data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And I tried using event.preventDefault();, but then button would not react at all.

Comment: You are making ajax call while submitting your form. Generally ajax is used when you don't want to submit the form but you want to call controller to perform some action or you want some part of your html page to get refreshed

Comment: Let me know if my solution worked .

Comment: Use console.log(error) instead of alert so that you can see the error properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not submit form while calling ajax . Try below code :

```
$(document).on('submit','form#myform',function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default submit action
  $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url: '/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/test.php',
           data: $('form').serialize(),
           success: function(data) {
              $( "#addEmilInfo").append( data);
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent form submit action and will call your ajax url without submitting the form

Comment: Do you have any problem?

Comment: Hi, this works but I have problem now. In my form there is two actions called when button is pressed, that's why I need to use on submit and plus in the form i have action which call's second php file. Now problem is that this one works, but it's stoping from calling other php action.

Comment: You can call other php action from success function of this ajax call..

Comment: Thanks, I made it work. I was trying to make in that way last time, but it did not want to work, probably because I did not add e.preventDefault();...Now it works both of them, thank you :)